# Table cells height calculated differenly in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, css-tables

The problem I face is IE 11 seem to have inconsistent `<td>` *inner height* across single `<tr>` while other browsers keep it the same.

Here's a pen illustrating my problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emKEBZ

In my layout I have an absolutely positioned pseudo-element (green border) which I want to display on a (outside) `<td>`. I'd like it to be always as high as the whole `<tr>` it is in. The content of `<td>`s is dynamic - I have no control over it's size (like I do in the pen).

I gave it `height: 100%`, assuming that every `<td>` in a row has the same height.

```
td {
  position: relative;
}

td:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -5px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

And yeah, that height calculates to the same value across all of the cells in the same row in Firefox and Chrome:

[image: Chrome and Firefox]

but to different height for each cell in IE 11:

[image: Ineternet Explorer 1]

The problem seems to be that in `height: 100%` IE refers to the *inner height* (the one inside the padding) of the containing `<td>`, while other browsers take *total height* (height + padding + border). And even then, the *inner height* of all `<td>`s along one `<tr>` is identical in Firefox, while it isn't in IE. Is any of those approaches wrong? Is there a way to force IE to work like other browsers do?

Comment: Have you got a CSS Reset in place?

Comment: @JamesGeorgeDunn Yes, I do.

Comment: This was a bug in IE that has recently been fixed. Future builds of our rendering engine will behave similar to Chrome/Firefox. I recently provided a work-around for [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27911771/54680). In the past, 100% was determined by the height of the content *within*, rather than the *offsetHeight* of the *cell itself*.

Comment: A work around I used was to just reference the absolutely positioned cells from the top instead of the bottom.  Good use of Illustration @Robert !

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to do that. Here is the code, hope it helps. [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/balintpekker/0utcLLy2/)

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll( "span.bar" ),
count = spans.length;
while ( count-- ) {
   spans[count].style.height = spans[count].parentElement.offsetHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
    padding:15px;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    cell-spacing: 0;    
}

tr {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
    vertical-align:center;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td .bar:first-child,
td .bar:last-child {
    display: block;
    background: green;
    width: 3px; 
    left: -5px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; top: 0; 
    z-index: 1;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #dedede;
    padding: 0px;
}

.tall {
    height: 100px;
}

.medium {
    height: 60px;
}

.short {
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding "0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="bar"></span><p class="tall">Save me!</p><span class="bar"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="bar"></span><p class="medium">From problems</p><span class="bar"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="bar"></span><p class="short">With IE</p><span class="bar"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I confirm it's working. But then not only it uses JavaScript, it also adds quite a lot of markup. I'll be waiting to see if that can't be done using only CSS. If not, I may use JavaScript, but without any extra markup. Still it seems you have put quite a work in writing your solution, so thank you very much for that.

Comment: @Robert I'm also curious if somebody could get it done using only CSS. As I searched and digged the whole internet today after this, it would be a surprise, but would be great to learn from.

Comment: It seems like some IE's oddity, so there's a big chance CSS won't fix that, but who knows...

Answer (score 0):

I will just add `margin` to total `100`

```
.tall {
  height: 100px;
}

.medium {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.short {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 35px 0;
}
```

Comment: In my real problem the content put inside `<td>` is dynamic - I can't predict it's size. I just made up those .short, .medium and .tall classes to illustrate the problem.

Comment: So as i know IEs doesnt affect height in percentage for `table-cell` and `table-row`

Comment: How can you explain that behavior then? You should run in IE the pen I provided. It'll display the problem in practice, so you can fiddle with it.

Answer (score 0):

Strange and interesting behavior by IE about table-cell here.
If you want an approach, you should put the cell on inline-block and set the height value, then align the content using line-height also reset the line-height for the text container like:

```
td {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 137px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 137px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #dedede;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Try on IE, I hope this will help you: http://codepen.io/pik_at/pen/WbyZrG

Comment: It would be good, but what happens, when one of the `<p>`'s got more than 137 pixel height?:)

Comment: @Pik_at I  can't set any fixed height, as the content of the cells will be of variable sizes and the cell should adjust to it.

Comment: In fact, Using position: relative in a table cell is not defined, look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17527089/4583260

Comment: But you're setting `height: 137px` on `td`. I need `td` to be as high (100%) as the whole `tr` it's in. And I can't set it to 137px, because I want responsive layout - I don' t know how high the row (or rather content inside it) will be for any of the rows.