# Strange behavior of vertical-align on table cell when cell contents are very small

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I found it impossible to center elements inside all of the 3 `<td>`s in a single `<tr>` because of the strange behavior of vertical-align.

My whole table is a datepicker and I need to have it's 2 side buttons (arrows) and the text in the middle all vertically centered. I thought `vertical-align: middle` on each of the containing `<th>` would do the case, but the arrows are somehow dragged down on Firefox:

[image: Firefox datepicker]

They are positioned well on Chrome:

[image: Chrome datepicker]

I tried to reconstruct the Firefox problem on a pen, but initially couldn't. Only after some fiddling did I found that weird behavior of `vertical-align` when the centered elements are small enough.

And so [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwxqjK) renders wrongly both on Firefox. Notice that this time I used `vertical-align: top` instead of `middle` as it better illustrate the problem. The black box should reach the sole top of the blue box, but for some reasons it doesn't until you increase it's height.

Here's screen from Firefox (where it touches the bottom instead of top!):

[image: Firefox pen]

And Chrome, where it's more in the middle than on the top:

[image: Chrome pen]

What's the reason of that behavior? How to align the elements properly in such case? I tried absolute positioning (giving `position: relative` to containing `<th>` and `position: absolute` to it's children elements), but I encountered a problem in IE calculating relative heights - I submitted the problem as [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763820/table-cells-height-calculated-differenly-in-ie11/28765217?noredirect=1#comment45809862_28765217). I should add that all the sizes are variable/dynamic and so the layout can't depend on any fixed-size calculations, but must be fully responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a workaround, but couldn't explain it properly. I think the problem is different type of children element inherits the `vertical-align` rule differently, i.e. `inline` and `block`. A workaround would be make the `<button>` to be block, same as the `<div>`.

```
button {
  display: block;
}
```

If you need further pixel perfect tweaking, you can also add:

```
.text {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

That makes it looks all the same on both Firefox and Chrome.

Demo here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPzaLg

Answer (score 1):

You added `vertical-align: top;` in the wrong place. Add it to the `<button>` instead, and watch out for margins too. Hope this helps.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

tr {
  background-color: #ededed;  
}

th {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.text {
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height:10px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <button></button>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="text">Text</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button></button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: It works ineed, when set on the children, so thanks for the solution. But then I didn't put it mistakenly in the wrong  place. When used on table cells, vertical-align aligns the content of the cell. For example "top - Align the top padding edge of the cell with the top of the row." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fvertical-align). So the question still remains - where does this strange behaviour comes from?

Comment: @Robert yes it is. You applied `vertical-align: top;` on the `th` element, which means all the `th` elements in that row will be aligned at the top of the row. It won't have effect to the child elements of the `th` so the reason is simply you didn't applied vertical align on the black area.

Comment: @ballintpekker As you said I applied on `th`, not on the `tr`, so obviously it could have no effect on all the cells in the row. And what "Align the top padding edge of the cell with the top of the row' means is that the elements (children) inside the cell will be aligned to the top edge of the cell (because there will be no top padding inside that cell). You can test that it works well, as soon as you change add `display: block` to `button` like @sdcr suggested.