# Position and size of ::before pseudo-elements in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

I made [this pedigree diagram](https://rawgit.com/damangio/inbreeding-calculator/2cec09d5c20a1a414e18ff16aae1b6409472e877/index.html) out of nested tables, using `::before` pseudo-elements to build the lines connecting the fields. It works great in Chrome and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer 11 the pseudo-elements are too short and in the wrong place.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#pedigree td:first-child {
    width: 8em;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
tr.s > td:first-child::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 2px;
    height: 50%;
    border: solid gray;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px
}
tr.d > td:first-child::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 2px;
    height: 50%;
    border: solid gray;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px
}
```

Each pseudo-element is supposed to be half the height of its containing `<td>`; for `.s` the bottom half, and for `.d` the top half. The pair of pseudo-elements together form a `[` shape.

In Chrome and Firefox, the `top`, `bottom`, and `height` are interpreted as percentages of the height of the `<td>`. In IE, they appear to be interpreted as percentages of the distance between the top of the `<td>` and the top of its content.

How can I make the appearance in IE match the other browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763820/table-cells-height-calculated-differenly-in-ie11

Comment: *You are free to accept an answer, if it helped you and you don't have any more questions.  **`:)`**  Otherwise feel free to ask.*

Comment: I haven't worked that project since I asked the question, but I will get back to it.

Answer (score 1):

Table-Elements don't behave like standard boxes. There are attributes which are not officially defined for such elements (as `position`). Some browsers implemented them anyway, and some didn't. Therefore you'll get strange/different behaviors.

---

Just use wrapping `div`s inside the `td` and apply all the styling (as well as pseudo elements) to this wrapper. Your tables would need a *height* specified as well.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/8dhwqvyj/1/

**HTML:**

```
[...]
<td>
    <div class="td-wrapper">
        <div class="td-content">
            <!-- cell content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
[...]
```

**CSS:**

```
table[data-level="0"] { height: 400px; }
table[data-level="1"] { height: 200px; }
table[data-level="2"] { height: 100px; }
table[data-level="3"] { height: 50px; }
table[data-level="4"] { height: 25px; }

#pedigree td:first-child > .td-wrapper {
    width: 10em;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
td > .td-wrapper > .td-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
tr.s > td:first-child > .td-wrapper::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 2px;
    height: 50%;
    border: solid gray;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px
}
tr.d > td:first-child > .td-wrapper::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 2px;
    height: 50%;
    border: solid gray;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px
}
```